# ProgrammingError: relation "django_session" does not exist error after installing Psycopg2

Tags: python, django, psycopg2, django-1.7

I started to develop a Django based web application. Everything was fine until I installed `Psycopg2` for my database which I created in `PostgreSql`. Now when I'm trying to open any page in my site, it throws `ProgrammingError: relation "django_session" does not exist` error.

```
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/
Django Version:     1.7
Exception Type:     ProgrammingError
Exception Value:    

relation "django_session" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ession_data", "django_session"."expire_date" FROM "django_se...
                                                             ^

Exception Location:     /home/alex/.virtualenvs/startDjango/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in execute, line 65
Python Executable:  /home/alex/.virtualenvs/startDjango/bin/python
```

This is my database setting in `settings.py`

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'myDB',
        'USER': 'alex',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

I'm developing in `virtualenvs`

Any idea how to fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 64, accepted):

If you change the database, you should create database for the new database.

Use [`manage.py migrate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/#migrate-app-label-migrationname) command. (or [`manage.py syncdb`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/#syncdb) if you used it for old database).

Answer (score 20):

You can alternatively migrate just the sessions app if you have already run migrate and still getting the error

```
python manage.py migrate sessions
```