# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "django_session" does not exist line 1

Tags: django, postgresql, django-database

I am using Django 1.8 
python 3.5

and recently completed one app which was using sqlite
and everything was fine

now i created a new app that i need to connect to a existing database on postgre ( in the same project folder )

i did the database inspectdb and got the models generated from it.

i didnt know how to setup two databases so i commented out the old "default"
database 
and wrote my settings for the new one. but when i try and go on the homepage of the app i get a server error and cmd.exe gives me this

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError" relation "django_session" does not exist LINE 1: ...ession_data", "django_session"."expire_date" FROM "django_se..
                                                                                                                                        ^
```

now i saw online i needed to migrate ( which i did )

and i saw as well i need to syncdb ( which i  did )

but nothing worked

but while trying to figure out i saw this way at the top of all the tracebacks

```
AttributeError: 'SessionStore' object has no  attribute '_session_cahce'




(landregtry1) C:\Sites\Landregistry>python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
September 26, 2016 - 11:06:36
Django version 1.8, using settings 'Landregistry.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\yfevrier\Envs\landregtry1\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sess
ions\backends\base.py", line 176, in _get_session
    return self._session_cache
AttributeError: 'SessionStore' object has no attribute '_session_cache'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\yfevrier\Envs\landregtry1\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\
utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "django_session" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ession_data", "django_session"."expire_date" FROM "django_se...
                                                             ^
```

Comment: please provide the full traceback. Error clearly says your **django_session** table is missing.

Comment: @dnit13 i found the issue 
postgresql doesnt have "django_sessions" table while my sqlite database does any i can force postgre to create it?

Comment: `python manage.py migrate` should create it.

Comment: @dnit13 it tells me no migrations to apply when i make migrations

Comment: if its a new database, you can simply delete the database and recreate it. This should solve your problem

Comment: Did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26220689/programmingerror-relation-django-session-does-not-exist-error-after-installin ?

Comment: @dnit13 I'm facing the same issue. how did you fix this?

Comment: @wizard are you running migrations against a new db? I so .. just drop your db and recreate it and then run the `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: @dnit13 I did that having the same issue: it's weird everything working fine without gunicorn. when I run with gunicorn it is giving me an error.

Comment: @wizard maybe your database pointing to a different location while running with gunicorn.

Answer (score 0):

python3 manage.py migrate --sync-db ( i think i am answering these questions years later)